# Question about unary languages

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, polynomial-time-reductions

Let $A$ be any unary language. Prove that if $A$ is NP-complete, then P=NP.

Approach 1: We just have to prove that we can decide $A$ in polynomial time. Consider a Turing machine that on input $w$, scans all the symbols of $w$. If they are all 1s, accept; otherwise, reject. This TM runs in polynomial time, so $A$ is in P, and thus P=NP.

Approach 2: Since $A$ is NP-complete, there is a function $f$ that reduces SAT to $A$ in polynomial time. Now we can design a TM machine for deciding SAT: on input $\langle \phi \rangle$, where $\phi$ is a boolean formula, compute $f(\langle \phi \rangle)$ and scan all its symbols. If all are 1s then accept; otherwise, reject.

Are these two approaches correct? If not, why not?

Comment: A unary language is not necessarily a language that contains all words made of $1$'s (it just doesn't contain words with other symbols).

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.